# Get Code Coverage for GWT project using Jacoco surefire

Tags: maven, gwt, code-coverage, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin

I am having GWT maven project and want to find code coverage.
I am getting the report with coverage as 0%.

pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512m</extraJvmArgs>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                    <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>${jacocoArgs}</argLine>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jboss.errai</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.4.201202141554</version>
        <configuration>
            <snapshotDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</snapshotDirectory>
            <propertyName>jacocoArgs</propertyName>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>jacoco-site</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>

        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

GWTTestCase

```
public class GwtTestCovergeSample extends GWTTestCase {

  public String getModuleName() {
    return "com.test.sample.CovergeSampleJUnit";
  }
  public void testFieldVerifier() {
  }
  public void testGreetingService() {
    GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);
    ServiceDefTarget target = (ServiceDefTarget) greetingService;
    target.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "CovergeSample/greet");

    delayTestFinish(10000);

    greetingService.greetServer("GWT User", new AsyncCallback<String>() {
      public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
          System.out.println("GwtTestCovergeSample.testGreetingService().new AsyncCallback() {...}.onFailure()");
        fail("Request failure: " + caught.getMessage());
      }
      public void onSuccess(String result) {
        assertTrue(result.startsWith("Hello, GWT User!"));
        finishTest();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

CoverageSampleJUnit.gwt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to="CovergeSample">
  <inherits name='com.test.sample.CovergeSample' />
  <servlet path="/CovergeSample/greet" class="com.test.sample.server.GreetingServiceImpl" />
</module>
```

In target folder, I can see site folder is getting created with correct report index.html file.
When I open index.html file coverage report is 0%.
Someone please help.